# Set EWMH properties, such as _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE, as a user?

Tags: x11, window-manager, i3, rofi

For example, rofi runs as `_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL` (or, as I think I understand from the code, otherwise inherits from a parent window), but I'd like it to be `_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_POPUP_MENU` in order to do something more generic in i3 & picom configs than matching on its class name.

I know I can `xprop -set`, but how can/where should I do that having matched its class? Or is this a complete abuse, and I should do it differently?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem

Comment: @lxhom Not that I recall/can see from my dotfiles, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

After a talk with Emanuele Torre(emanuele6) on matrix/IRC channel he provided this solution:

```
rofi -show &
rofi_pid=$! rofi_wid=$(xdo id -mp "$rofi_pid") &&
   xprop -id "$rofi_wid" \
         -f _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE 32a \
         -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_POPUP_MENU
```

quote emanuele6:

> so basically    exec rofi ... &   is your rofi command  rofi_pid=$!
> is the pid of the new rofi process   rofi_wid=$(xdo id -mp
> "$rofi_pid")  waits until a window with that _NET_WM_PID exists and
> then outputs its wid and finally xprop sets that atom to what you want

This indeed sets `_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE`, but (at least for me) picom won't apply animations (not sure if window was already mapped).

Other option would be use rofi flag `-normal-window`

I use bspwm with `rofi ... -normal-window`, so in external_rules I have set:

```
# rofi set _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE
# bspwm doesn't manage these windows because rofi overrides redirect by default
case "$class" in
  (*Rofi*)
    #echo "manage=off" #this will break rofi focus don't use this
    echo "layer=above"
    echo "focus=on"
    echo "state=floating"
    xprop -id "$wid" \
          -f _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE 32a \
          -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_POPUP_MENU
  ;;
esac
```